# Reversing a singly linked list in java

Tags: java, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I made a singly linked list from scratch in java. The code is as follows:

```
public class SingleLinkedList<Item>
{
private Node head;
private int size;

private class Node
{
    Item data;
    Node next;

    public Node(Item data)
    {
        this.data = data;
        this.next = null;
    }

    public Node(Item data, Node next)
    {
        this.data = data;
        this.next = next;
    }
    //Getters and setters
    public Item getData()
    {
        return data;
    }
    public void setData(Item data)
    {
        this.data = data;
    }
    public Node getNext()
    {
        return next;
    }
    public void setNext(Node next)
    {
        this.next = next;
    }

}

public SingleLinkedList()
{
    head = new Node(null);
    size = 0;
}

public void add(Item data)
{
    Node temp = new Node(data);
    Node current = head;

    while(current.getNext() != null)
    {
        current = current.getNext();
    }

    current.setNext(temp);
    size++;
}

public void add(Item data, int index)
{
    Node temp = new Node(data);
    Node current = head;

    for(int i=0; i<index && current.getNext() != null; i++)
    {
        current = current.getNext();
    }

    temp.setNext(current.getNext());
    current.setNext(temp);
    size++;
}

public Item get(int index)
{
    if(index <= 0)
    {
        return null;
    }

    Node current = head;

    for(int i=1; i<index; i++)
    {
        if(current.getNext() == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        current = current.getNext();
    }

    return current.getData();
}

public boolean remove(int index)
{
    if(index < 1 || index > size())
    {
        return false;
    }

    Node current = head;
    for(int i=1; i<index; i++)
    {
        if(current.getNext() == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        current = current.getNext();
    }

    current.setNext(current.getNext().getNext());
    size--;
    return true;
}

public String toString()
{
    Node current = head.getNext();
    String output = "";
    while(current != null)
    {
        output+=current.getData().toString()+"  ";
        current = current.getNext();
    }

    return output;
}

public int size()
{
    return size;
}

public void reverse()
{
    Node current = head;
    Node prevNode = null;
    Node nextNode;

    while(current!=null)
    {
        nextNode = current.getNext();
        current.setNext(prevNode);
        prevNode = current;
        current = nextNode;
        System.out.println(prevNode.getData());
    }

    head = prevNode;

}
```

}

As you can see, I added the reverse function in the class only.

But when I tried actually using the class it gave NullPointerException after I tried to reverse it.

To check the functionality I used another class called TEST. The code is as follows:

```
public class TEST
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SingleLinkedList<Integer> list = new SingleLinkedList<Integer>();

        list.add(1);
        list.add(2);
        list.add(3);
        list.add(4);
        list.add(5);

        System.out.println(list.toString());

        list.reverse();
        System.out.println(list.toString());

    }
}
```

The output is as follows:

```
1  2  3  4  5  
null
1
2
3
4
5
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at SingleLinkedList.toString(SingleLinkedList.java:129)
    at TEST.main(TEST.java:20)
```

I tried to print the value of prevNode to check whether its not taking values...but it is.
What to do?

Comment: For problems like this the best approach is to take paper and pencil and to draw an example and how the pointers change by your actions in the program.

Comment: I tried all that. Couldn't find anything. MAybe its the way I'm doing it but still I am stuck. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, your reverse method looks fine.

The problem is your toString() method.
When you create a new list, you create an initial element whose data is null.
Your `toString` method skips that first element, so it works fine as long as you don't reverse the list.
But when you reverse the list, that null element becomes the last element, and when you call `output+=current.getData().toString()+"  ";` for that last element when `current.getData()` is null, you get `NullPointerException`.

You have several options :

1. Your reverse method can keep the initial null element first (i.e. reverse the rest of the list, but keep the head the same). This way toString can remain unchanged.
2. Eliminate the initial null element. Then your toString method doesn't have to skip anything.

Keeping the null element first :

```
public void reverse()
{
    Node current = head.getNext();
    Node prevNode = null;
    Node nextNode;

    while(current!=null)
    {
        nextNode = current.getNext();
        current.setNext(prevNode);
        prevNode = current;
        current = nextNode;
        System.out.println(prevNode.getData());
    }

    head.setNext(prevNode);

}
```

Comment: @abhyuditjain add some suggestions

Comment: Please don't mind my poor knowledge. I am new. Just learning. I didn't completely understand what you're trying to say. But I tried implementing the changes and now there are 2 problems: (1) Last node is not displayed AFTER reversing and (2) toString() is working after reversing if I implement the change.

Comment: @abhyuditjain added suggested fix to reverse. didn't test it though. the alternative fix requires changes in more methods, so I leave it to you if you choose to try it.

Comment: @abhyuditjain did you try the code I just posted? you don't have to change toString

Answer (score 0):

```
 while(current!=null)
```

This is your problem. When you hit the last node the 'next' node you get is actually null.

<s>Try changing it to</s>

```
while(current!=null&&current.getNext()!=null)
```

<s>EDIT: Actually not sure that solution will work. Try putting a conditional at the end of your loop that says:</s>

```
if(current.getNext()==null)
    break;
```

EDIT (again :/):

ok sorry I wasn't thinking straight.

change that final if statement to:

```
if(current.getNext()==null){
    current.setNext(prevNode);
    break;
}
```

The actual nullpointer is in the toString. Here's what you do:

Change the while conditional to

```
while(current != null&&current.getData()!=null)
```

Because otherwise if current points to null then you get an exception.

That was exhausting.

Comment: I tried this but now the last node is not displayed at all.

Comment: The first one didn't do anything different. The second one also gives the nullpointerexception

Comment: Ok I'm going to actually test this one moment

Comment: Not working :(   Same error.  Am fed up with this now :x

Comment: Thank you for your effort but last node is not getting displayed no matter what. toString() method works either before reversing or after no matter what I try.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your SingleLinkedList.java toString() method

Try below it is working fine

```
    public String toString() {
        Node current = head;
        String output = "";
        while (current != null) {
//            output += current.getData().toString() + "  ";
            output += String.valueOf(current.getData()) + "  ";
            current = current.getNext();
        }

        return output;
    }
```

Comment: Eran solved my problem without changing the toString() method. Thanks anyway.